# Understanding Direct Mapped Cache

Tags: caching, memory, memory-management, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I'm trying to understand direct mapped cache, but it is a very complex concept. I have written what I think I understand so far, but I am unsure whether I am correct or not. Can somebody please verify if the explanation below is correct?

E.g, for a made up computer, just for the sake of this question, there 1024 memory locations (cells) in the RAM. This equals 2^10 so the address for each of these memory locations must be 10 bits long.

The CPU is asked to get data from the RAM memory address `1100100111`. However the CPU doesn't access the data directly from this memory address in the RAM. The RAM stores this data to cache memory and then the CPU gets the data from the cache memory.

There are different ways of doing this, one being direct mapped cache. The cache memory and ram memory are divided up into blocks, where the number of cells in the blocks in each memory must be the same. The number of blocks in the RAM and cache must also be a power of 2.

In this example lets say there are 2^6 = 64 blocks in the RAM, so there are 1024/64 = 16 cells in each block. Lets say there are 2^2 = 4 blocks in the cache, so the cache has 64 cells. The "6" and "2" in the exponents of these numbers are important later on.

Because the The number of blocks in the RAM and cache is a power of 2, it makes the calculations easy. In our address  `1100100111` the last 6 bits mark the offset `100111` (the 6 comes from the fact that 2^6 = 64), and the remaining 4 bits `1100` mark the RAM block number the data is stored in. Within this block number are two other important numbers. First the cache block number; this is the cache block that that RAM block would store to. This is the first 2 bits after the offset, so it will be `00` (The 2 comes from the fact that There are 2^2 = 4 blocks in the cache). The remaining 2 numbers in the address mark the tag. This will be `11`.

So when the CPU is asked to get data from memory address `1100100111` it will look for this data in cache block number `00`. It will compare the tag of the address `11` to the tag saved in the cache, which is a separate piece of memory used to store information about where from the RAM the data has come from. If the tags are the same this is a hit and this is the data the CPU is looking for. If the tag of the address and the tag in the memory are different, then this is a miss, and the data isn't stored in the cache.

If this is the case, the cache controller will get the data from block number `1100` in the RAM and store  it in the cache block number `00`, and update the tag in this block to `11`. The CPU can now get the data in this block.

Is this all correct? I need to understand this before I can start to try and understand associative and set associative memory.

[image: Memory Address]

Thanks!

Comment: Offset should mark the "cell" location within a "block" - you have 16 such cells per block, so you only need 4 bits, not 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea, but your numbers went wrong somewhere. In your example you have a direct-mapped cache of 4 blocks/lines of 16 bytes/cells each. The address `1100100111` will be divided up as follows. You use the least significant four bits `0111` as the offset because it refers to which cell of a particular block you want. I think you accidentally included the block number as part of the offset. Anyway, the next least significant two bits `10` will be the block number and the most significant four bits `1100` will be the tag.

Your understanding seems to be fine. One thing more that is necessary is a bit to indicate if the cache block is valid or not. Good luck with the associative stuff!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and sorry for the late reply. I've had a lot of revision these past weeks. Can I just ask, if `10` is the block number in the cache, and the most significant four bits `1100` are the tag, will the block that this piece of data is stored in in the main memory (RAM) be in block number `101100` ?

Comment: No, in this mapping scheme the tag should precede the block number. The location in memory where the block starts is `1100100000` and the location of the last cell of this block is `1100101111`. Therefore the block number in RAM is `110010`, although it's not really typical to refer to refer a block number in the main memory. The concept applies to the caches.

Comment: If you refer to the diagram you posted you'll notice why.